# validacion de datos php, html js

Tags: php, mysql, html5, css3

actualmente mantengo una pagina web en la que surgio el siguiente inconveniente: es una pagina que tiene un ecommerce disponible y una vez que el cliente esta registrado y quiere completar los datos de contacto (nombre y apellido, direccion, codigo postal y mail) cada vez que se guardan los cambios el formulario pone el email en el campo de codigo postal y el codigo postal en el mail? a donde deberia buscar el error? soy nueva en el rubro y los progrtamadores del sitio me dejaron el codigo fuente hecho un desastre. Gracias!!

Comment: Deberías buscar en tu formulario que el Id del input corresponda al mismo en el JS y por ultimo en el controlador.Creo deberías mostrar el código para una respuesta más concreta. SALUDOS!!!

Comment: Tienes que verificar el id y el name que estas enviando , y si los envias por un insert verificar que la variable este en el lugar correspondiente .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que explicas, lo mas obvio es que es por el orden del `INSERT INTO`. En los `values` "..." debes tener intercambiadas las variables, un ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO mail, codigo_postal VALUES "'$codigo_postal', '$mail'"
```

(Lo comento por que es algo que me suele pasar)